# Data crawled has different units used for same data/field. How to standardize the units before writing them into the DB

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, web-crawler

I am crawling the data from some websites which has some fields like *"amount"*, *"weight"* etc.

For *"amount"* field the values I am getting are like:
`"$ 75 Thousand", "$ 1.2 Lakh", "$ 1500" etc.`
And similarly for *"weight"* the values are like:
`"15 Kg", "25 Kgs", "600 gm", "15,000 gm" etc.`

How to standardize all these values to a same unit before writing them to the DB?
And also if I want to convert these values to a number instead of string after standardizing the unit, how to do that?

I am using MongoDB as a datastore. Does MongoDB have any inbuilt option for this?

Comment: If want to standardize them before writing to MongoDB, then your application should handle that, if the data is already written to the DB, then you can write an aggregation pipeline

Comment: Thanks @CharchitKapoor. That would be great help if you can further explain on how to do it with aggregation pipeline for the given data or what would be the logic for doing it at application end.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to standardize the data before it ends up in your data store (MongoDB for you).

You don't specify which crawler you are currently using, but with [Norconex Web Crawler](https://opensource.norconex.com/crawlers/web/), there are a few options available to you. I'm listing them here in order of complexity.

1. [ReplaceTagger](https://opensource.norconex.com/importer/v3/apidocs/com/norconex/importer/handler/tagger/impl/ReplaceTagger.html).
   The following example replaces occurrences of "Thousand" with "000" in the "amount" field.

```
<handler class="ReplaceTagger">
  <replace>
    <fieldMatcher>amount</fieldMatcher>
    <valueMatcher replaceAll="true">
      Thousand
    </valueMatcher>
    <toValue>000</toValue>
  </replace>
</handler>
```

You can add multiple `<replace>` tags.

2.[RegexTagger](https://opensource.norconex.com/importer/v3/apidocs/com/norconex/importer/handler/tagger/impl/RegexTagger.html).

```
<handler class="RegexTagger">
  <pattern toField="emails">
    [A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+?@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
  </pattern>
  <pattern
      fieldGroup="1"
      valueGroup="2">
    <![CDATA[
     <tr><td class="label">(.*?)</td><td class="value">(.*?)</td></tr>
   ]]>
  </pattern>
</handler>
```

The first pattern in the above example extracts what look like email addresses in to an "email" field (simplified regex). The second pattern extracts field names and values from "label" and "value" cells on a given HTML table.

For more complex use cases, you can provide your own script.

3. [ScriptTagger](https://opensource.norconex.com/importer/v3/apidocs/com/norconex/importer/handler/tagger/impl/ScriptTagger.html)
   The following example replaces occurrences of `Thousand` with `000` in the `amount` field.

```
<handler class="ScriptTagger">
  <script>
    <![CDATA[
      amount = metadata.getString('amount', 'a default value').replace(/Thousand/g, '000');
      metadata.set('amount', amount);
    ]]>
  </script>
</handler>
```

4. If there is a need to modify the entire document as you see fit, there is the [ScriptTransformer](https://opensource.norconex.com/importer/v3/apidocs/com/norconex/importer/handler/transformer/impl/ScriptTransformer.html). It works in a similar fashion as `ScriptTagger`, just that it allows you to modify the document content as well.

Disclaimer: I work for Norconex.